# Change wired connection icon in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, icons, themes

[image]

No matter which icon theme I use ( Tela, Humanity, Ubuntu Mono light, Adwaita ) the `wired connection` icon remains the same. Personally, I feel that an `ethernet` symbol would be more attractive. It would nice if I can customise it somehow. I can make the icon, but not sure where to change them.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set Icons themes to Adwaita (default) then refresh gnome desktop (alt+f2 then type r then press enter). Also if you're using custom Shell theme, change it to default then do the Icon change and change shell theme beck (if you want to). Also try hovering over the icons if it doesn't cha

Answer (score 0):

`network-wired-symbolic.svg` icon was missing and I used Inkscape to create one and added to `Symbolic > Status`

Now I have a proper symbol which indicates a wired connection

[image]